# Matlab and .NET 4.0 data communication

Tags: c#, .net, matlab, inter-process-communicat

I have an algorithm implemented in Matlab and I'm planning to deploy it as a DLL for integration with a .NET project. The .NET project is a GUI based application a small part of which consists of displaying the results obtained from running the algorithm. The problem I currently have is that I need to display intermediary results. The algorithm is quite intricate and runs for a number of iterations (chosen by the user) and at the end of each iteration the GUI should be updated with the current data.

The best solution that I have in mind at the moment is for the Matlab thread to act as a tcp client to the local tcp server that I would start in my C# GUI app. However, I feel this approach is inefficient. I was wondering whether this could be achieved some other way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, judging by your question, I guess you know about [Matlab builder NE](http://www.mathworks.com/products/netbuilder/). It allows you to deploy a .NET DLL. If you don't know, try it.

### Regarding your options:

1) You can pass a .NET object to your Matlab code that will serve as a communications means. 
Create a new instance of this class, and send to your Matlab code as input. The Matlab code will call the **UpdateGui**  logic with each iteraion. The following example is in **C#**

```
 class GuiUpdater{
      public void UpdateGui(int param1,int param2){
           //Do update logic here.
      }
 }
```

2) Compile your DLL as COM (It is also possible in Matlab Builder NE), and use COM communication.
3) Use the filesystem as communication means. Write to a file in Matlab, and read it in .NET.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, wouldn't using solution 1 mean that the GuiUpdater would have to have visibility to the whole GUI code? Wouldn't this in turn mean that the whole C# project would be bundled in the DLL?

Comment: @filipcampeanu, Yes, the GuiUpdater would have to have access to the whole GUI. I don't understand your second question, please explain.

Comment: Sorry, I was being confusing. The solution seems nice but I can't integrate it with my project. I was thinking about the alternative of wrapping a Matlab object around the algorithm code, deploying it as a DLL, instantiating it in C# and calling methods on that object from C#. I am not sure, however that one can do this. For example I've tried instantiating a class with MWArray[] result = matlab.MyClass(1, input), but by the end of the call result contains one null element (which should in fact have been the reference to the instantiated object). I am wondering whether this is possible.