# Run matlab from C# and give parameter to matlab

Tags: c#, matlab

I have a C# program which should call Matlab for running a m-file and so Matlab program read parameters from a text file that may be vary on situations.

I want a like this:

```
Execute(Matlab.exe,"matlabprog.m","input_parameters_file.txt");
```

It is good for me if i know when this instance of Matlab terminate running.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider using the Matlab engine or compile a .NET Assembly using the Matlab Builder NA.
Also check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813407/matlab-and-net-4-0-data-communication/8815598#8815598), in which I explain some of the possibilities.

Comment: this would probably be the better option

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at the [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) method:

```
 var process = Process.Start("matlab.exe", 
                             "matlabprog.m input_parameters_file.txt");
 process.WaitForExit();
```