# How to I integrate C# GUI with matlab functions and deploy a single installer file

Tags: c#, matlab

I have created a software using matlab but used c# for GUI since I am new to MATLAB and GUI in MATLAB didn't look according to requirement.
Now I want to create an installer for the application like setup.exe
so people can install it without having visual studio or/and matlab.
I have tried to search but couldn't get any satisfactory answer.
I am using matlab 2017b and Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we create GUI in C# that will run the MATLAB code in back hand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18726775/can-we-create-gui-in-c-sharp-that-will-run-the-matlab-code-in-back-hand)

Comment: Matlab requireds a license or install the runtime library.  To run matlab you either need the same version of matlab install on deploy PC or install the runtime library for Matlab that matches the machine where it was compiled.

Comment: I am  trying to create a stand alone exe file using visual studio. I want to bundle librares of matlab functions with .exe file

Comment: no duplicate. I checked that one, I have like 5 to 6 files containing matlab code.