# How to create dll's in matlab and use these dll's in .Net applications

Tags: c#, .net, matlab

I am working on image processing. I need to develop OCR tool using matlab. Is there any technique to develop OCR tool, create the dll of it and use it in .Net applications. If yes, how can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813407/matlab-and-net-4-0-data-communication/8815598#8815598

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try the MathWorks website.  Looks like they have examples there of creating mex files and using them in a .NET application.  See [Making and debugging mex with Visual Studio 2010 and Matlab 2009b](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26490-example-making-and-debugging-mex-with-visual-studio-2010-and-matlab-2009b)

[Here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12987-integrating-matlab-with-c) is an example that shows 3 different ways to integrate matlab with C#

Comment: The second link is not available. You should have posted at least a summary of what was present in the link.

Answer (score 3):

you need to use matlab Builder NE for stuff like that. you can compile any matlab function load the Dll in .net as a class with a function.
for that you need to use Matlab Compiler Runtime - MCR of the same version as the matlab you used with Builder NE.